# Setting a Java breakpoint on a one-line conditional return statement

Tags: java, debugging, ide, breakpoints

Do any Java debuggers allow you to set a breakpoint on the `someOperation();` method invocation statement in the following statement?

```
if (someCondition()) someOperation();
```

Note that I'm looking for an answer to a very specific question here.

1. I am not interested in setting a conditional breakpoint on the line that evaluates `someCondition()` to determine when the appropriate time to halt is.
2. I am not interested in setting a breakpoint inside the `someOperation()` method.
3. I am not interested in the case where the condition and method call statement are on different lines.

Comment: Eclipse allows to set method breakpoints which should be helpful AFAIK

Comment: Did you check Netbeans?

Comment: @NarendraPathai he is not interested in setting a breakpoint inside the someValue() method.

Comment: @NarendraPathai those aren't relevant to this question. I think my use of a `return` statement may have been misleading, so I edited the question to clarify that the conditional statement is an arbitrary statement inside the conditional (now `someOperation();`).

Comment: Can you also explain what the use case is now that the constraints are clear?

Comment: I see, you're looking to add this into your IDE :)

Comment: I have nearly completed an implementation of this feature in the debugger I'm integrating into Visual Studio. It required me to get... "creative"... so I want to see if any other IDEs have been able to do it in the past. Here's my recent tweet related to the debugger, although it doesn't concern this feature specifically: https://twitter.com/samharwell/status/312051828009361409

Comment: My implementation also lets you set separate breakpoints on the initializer (`int i = 0`), condition (`i < 10`), and increment (`i++`) portions of the following, even if it all falls on the same line: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Comment: Can you describe the actual use case?  Most developers who use IDE's also use hotswap, where they could easily separate lines of code out, which for debugging, is usually easier on the eyes anyway...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26218/discussion-between-280z28-and-amir-afghani)

Comment: How would you specify this to the debugger other than by clicking in the source and say _right here_?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen If you execute the Toggle Breakpoint command in Visual Studio while the caret is on the equivalent of `someOperation()` in C# code, it will set a breakpoint on just that statement without a problem. That is coupled with having both Line and Character fields in the breakpoint location properties dialog, where Java IDEs tend to have only a Line option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated my blog with a new article discussing the current state of [Tunnel Vision Labs' Java debugger for Visual Studio](http://blog.280z28.org/archives/2013/03/138/). In the article, I included the following animated image showing the *current behavior* of this debugger.

[image: Individual Statement Stepping]

Comment: +1 I do not know what is it about, but I definitely like the animgif :)

Comment: When I started to open console java application I got that error when  I tried to debug my code I got this message This preview version of the Java debugger only supports starting execution in a named class; the class name may be configured in the project properties on the Debug tab.
 Sir, Do you have any idea according to this ?